# Execlp user library function

Tags: linux, shell

I've recently run into a question like this:

If you use execlp into a function and you have some more code below, in which situation will this code be executed?

For example:

```
execlp("ps","ps","-u","username",(char*) NULL);
```

some more code below --> what does its execution depend on?

Does it depend on the `exit status` of the program executed by `execlp`? Or will it be executed anyway because execlp does its stuff independently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that would happen is if `execlp` itself failed.  Once the new program has been exec'd, it does not matter if that program succeeds or fails--it's already too late to go back to the original program instructions.